# Compiling omniORB with minGW error : undefined reference to `wWinMain', even if -municode used

Tags: c++, c, unicode, mingw-w64, omniorb

I'm newbee with minGW. I'm trying to compile omniORB 4.2.3 with minGW in order to link the libraries with my applications developed on Dev-CPP 5.11 . I use the same toolchain for both. The gcc version is 4.9.2 (tdm64-1).
I googled everywhere as possible and found the linker option `-municode`. But the error persists. I tried the wrapper solution too.

Here is the lines of the error :

```
+ gcc -oomnicpp.exe -mthreads -Wl,--enable-runtime-pseudo-reloc -municode -L../../../../../lib/x86_win32 cexp.o cccp.o config.o alloca.o index.o
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libmingw32.a(lib64_libmingw32_a-crt0_w.o): In function `wmain':
C:/crossdev/src/mingw-w64-v3-git/mingw-w64-crt/crt/crt0_w.c:23: undefined reference to `wWinMain'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Are you using `-Wl,--subsystem,windows`?

Comment: If there are C++ sources in the code then you should use `g++` as the linker, not `gcc`

Comment: have you got a `main` function in one of those `.o` files?

Comment: 1 I forgot : I tried -Wl,--subsystem,windows yet with or without -municode : same result

Comment: 2 I'll try g++ instead ; In this case that's meaning a big error in the library (that's not mine)

Comment: 3 I have main and not wWinMain function in the sources

Comment: I tried g++ instead of gcc : the error persists

Comment: After hours I found the solution : the missing linker option is :  -Wl,--subsystem,console

Comment: You might want to consider updating your gcc, 4.9.2 is 6 years old.